Springboot Thymeleaf form submission showing NULL and blank values NOT showing entered values
Springboot Thymeleaf form submission showing NULL and blank values NOT showing entered values on said form ....as instructed filling up more space so i can post...if you need more details please let me know!!
Controller -> TacoDesign
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/design")
public class ControllerDesignTaco {
    private static final Logger logger2= LoggerFactory.getLogger(ControllerDesignTaco.class);
    
    @GetMapping
    public String showDesignForm(Model obj_model_map){ 
        List<DomainTacoIngredient> ingredients = Arrays.asList(
                new DomainTacoIngredient("FLTO", "Flour Tortilla", Type.WRAP),
                new DomainTacoIngredient("COTO", "Corn Tortilla", Type.WRAP),
                new DomainTacoIngredient("GRBF", "Ground Beef", Type.PROTEIN),
                new DomainTacoIngredient("CARN", "Carnitas", Type.PROTEIN),
                new DomainTacoIngredient("TMTO", "Diced Tomatoes", Type.VEGGIES),
                new DomainTacoIngredient("LETC", "Lettuce", Type.VEGGIES),
                new DomainTacoIngredient("CHED", "Cheddar", Type.CHEESE),
                new DomainTacoIngredient("JACK", "Monterrey Jack", Type.CHEESE),
                new DomainTacoIngredient("SLSA", "Salsa", Type.SAUCE),
                new DomainTacoIngredient("SRCR", "Sour Cream", Type.SAUCE)
                );
            
        Type types[] = DomainTacoIngredient.Type.values();
        for (Type type : types) {
            System.out.println(
obj_model_map.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(),filterByType(ingredients, type)));
            System.out.println(type.toString());
        }
                
        System.out.println(obj_model_map.addAttribute("design", new DomainTacoDesign()));       
        Map<String, Object> obj_Map_model_map= obj_model_map.asMap();
        obj_Map_model_map.forEach((map_key,map_val)->
            System.out.println("key=" + map_key+ ",value="+ map_val)
        );
        return "design";
    }
    
    @PostMapping
    public String processDesign(/*@RequestBody*/ @Valid @ModelAttribute("design") DomainTacoDesign ingredient, BindingResult obj_binding_result1,Model obj_model_map, HttpServletRequest obj_http_servlet_request1, Errors obj_err1){
        if(obj_binding_result1.hasErrors()){
            //get ALL errors
            System.out.println(obj_binding_result1.getAllErrors());
        }
        
        if(obj_err1.hasErrors()){
            System.out.println(obj_err1.getAllErrors());
            return "design";
        }
        
        System.out.println(
obj_http_servlet_request1.getParameterNames());
        
        Enumeration<String> obj_enum_strngs_obj_http_servlet_request1= obj_http_servlet_request1.getParameterNames();
        
        for(Enumeration <String> objenumstr= obj_enum_strngs_obj_http_servlet_request1; obj_enum_strngs_obj_http_servlet_request1.hasMoreElements();){
            System.out.println(objenumstr.nextElement());
        }
            System.out.println(obj_model_map.addAttribute("name",ingredient.getName()));                 System.out.println(obj_model_map.addAttribute("class",ingredient.getClass()));
        logger2.info("Processing design-> ingredient: {} ", ingredient);
        logger2.info("Processing design-> ingredient.name: {} ", ingredient.name);
        
        return "redirect:/orders/current";
    }
    
    private List<DomainTacoIngredient> filterByType(List<DomainTacoIngredient> ingredients, Type type) {
        return ingredients.stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getType().equals(type))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
    }   

when submitting design  form on localhost:
ingredients
name
{design=com.example.demo.DomainTacoDesign@3ee4d959, org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.design=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors, name=null}
{design=com.example.demo.DomainTacoDesign@3ee4d959, org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.design=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors, name=null, class=class com.example.demo.DomainTacoDesign}
2024-07-11T18:35:28.162-04:00  INFO 25076 --- [nio-8090-exec-9] com.example.demo.ControllerDesignTaco    : Processing design-> ingredient: com.example.demo.DomainTacoDesign@3ee4d959 
2024-07-11T18:35:28.162-04:00  INFO 25076 --- [nio-8090-exec-9] com.example.demo.ControllerDesignTaco    : Processing design-> ingredient.name: null 
{order=com.example.demo.DomainTacoOrder@2315f02}
key=order,value=com.example.demo.DomainTacoOrder@2315f02

DesignForm view Thymeleaf:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Taco Cloud</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Design your taco!!</h1>
    <img th:src="@{/staic/images/tacopic11.png}"/>
    <form method="POST" th:object="${design}">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="ingredient-group" id="wraps">
        <h3>Designate your wrap:</h3>
        <div th:each="ingredient : ${wrap}">
            <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
            <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ingredient-group" id="proteins">
        <h3>Pick your protein:</h3>
        <div th:each="ingredient : ${protein}">
            <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
            <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
        </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="ingredient-group" id="cheeses">
        <h3>Choose your cheese:</h3>
        <div th:each="ingredient : ${cheese}">
            <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
        <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ingredient-group" id="veggies">
        <h3>Determine your veggies:</h3>
        <div th:each="ingredient : ${veggies}">
            <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
            <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ingredient-group" id="sauces">
        <h3>Select your sauce:</h3>
        <div th:each="ingredient : ${sauce}">
            <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
            <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            
            
        <h3>Name your taco creation:</h3>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
        <br/>
        <button>Submit your taco</button>
        </div>
    </form>
            
</body>
</html>




This is impossible to read. First of all correctly format also log messages as code. Second - don' t post links to whatever google drive (which btw requires access), show relevant code here. Thirdly - don't just dump all of your code - makes harder for us to go through, remove everything irrelevant. In this case, since your problem is form submission - just provide the view (html) code of the template for form and the controller code

thanks for input.. hope this helps .. please do let me know any further  business logic mvc concentrations, etc... that need to be supplied. thanks much!

I am still confused which of the two forms is not working? order or design? Please pick one (even if both are not working) and show code relelvant to only one of them (one problem at a time)

@ModelAttribute("order") - that is not where you put this annotation, this is to pass an object from controller to the view, just removed that annotation from controller parameters

In any case why are we even figuring this out, this is literally the code from Spring in Action - but you are messing up the annotations (e.g. @RequestBody should only be used for RestControllers, and @ModelAttribute is used on separate methods (not parameters) to pass the object to view). Just go back to the book's code, and then make your changes in very small doses, constantly checking if you broke something

thanks...both of the forms. will alter to only one form since solution from one would probably transfer....after post->  values becoming null....in an attempt to understand the logic of  MVC pattern utilized in Spring deeply from ground up with added error objects + logs+ added essential annotations i am referring to example from said Spring Action book..there seems to be quite a bit rather than just following the book to understand from ground up + also some of the utilities are outdaded..yes modular incremental changes in small doses..

with respect to the RequestBody my understanding is it is deserialization from byte stream -> object ?? but since the view is thymeleaf then do NOT need ResponseBody since controller-> view is thymeleaf. And from my understanding RestController already includes both said annotations but on a class level?   and so from my understanding ModelAttribute  is needed to access a form backing domain object such as DomainTacoDesign  and if you use as function parameters-> will use arguments from the model -> and said model argument fields should populate from respective form view  fields

also if when removing ModelAttribute from function parameters i think bc access is lost to the respective form backing object.. result in error fallback
